# How to display the 'No of leaves' in payslip of OpenERP

Tags: odoo

I am working with the customization of HR module in OpenERP. What are the steps which I should follow to display value in "No of leaves" field of the payslip in HR module?

I have tried different methods like:

1. Allocating leaves to employees
2. Employee requesting for leaves.
3. Employee leaves approved.

Even after the leaves for an employee is approved, the "No of leaves" field in payslip remains zero for that employee.

Have I missed any steps?

Please help!!!!

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you can show what you have so far. Have you created a new module?

Comment: @Alchemist777 , I am working now on customization of HR module in OpenERP . I am vote Up Your question I need your helping in this field 
Please , I want to calculate deduction from salary (Absence or leave) 
 And I can not put a question in stack overflow  How can you help Please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't quite see where number of leaves would appear on the payslip, so I couldn't really track down what you're asking for, but I can offer some hints.

Under `hr_payroll.hr_payslip.get_worked_day_lines()` is a helper function [`was_on_leave()`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-addons/trunk/view/6651/hr_payroll/hr_payroll.py#L408).

```
    def was_on_leave(employee_id, datetime_day, context=None):
        res = False
        day = datetime_day.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        holiday_ids = self.pool.get('hr.holidays').search(cr, uid, [
            ('state','=','validate'),
            ('employee_id','=',employee_id),
            ('type','=','remove'),
            ('date_from','<=',day),
            ('date_to','>=',day)])
        if holiday_ids:
            res = self.pool.get('hr.holidays').browse(
                cr, 
                uid, 
                holiday_ids, 
                context=context)[0].holiday_status_id.name
        return res
```

As you can see, it sounds like you're already getting the correct state. ("validate" appears as "Approve" on screen.) You didn't mention whether you set up the employee's holiday type correctly. ("remove" appears as "Leave Request" on screen.)

Other than that, either the dates are wrong, or I'm looking at something unrelated.

Comment: Thanks Don..sorry for the late response.                                                         Is there any method to link attendances,leaves and the payslip. ie when an employee is on leave,then his leave will be automatically deducted from the alocated number of leaves.If the leave becomes an LOP,then it should come in the payslip as well..any ideas on this one??

Comment: Sorry, @Alchemist777, I don't understand your question. I suggest you ask a separate question where you describe in detail what you're trying to do and what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

As per My knowledge , if the leave type is paid then the leave count is not shown in field "No. of leave" in Report(Employee Pay Slip) . Make a Change to your leave type to Unpaid and try it out again ,im sure you can get it .This time the leave count will be shown in Report